# Suggestion for shopping cart update

Tags: php, security, session, shopping-cart

I am working on a shopping on a online store for my brother. I am stuck in the in the process where the buyers cart is updated when he adds items to the basket . I want to know how to remember the buyer (as my bro wants user can buy without sign in,so no case of user id etc)? Should I create a session for him and save it to database?

Comment: I'm not against "rolling your own", but just curious as to if you've given consideration to using any of the dozens of open source e-commerce apps available for PHP?

Comment: Actually I am using an MVC framework and I want to create my own CMS so that it is easier to control for me !

Comment: If you are using an MVC, search through their docs as Sessions is a very common component with frameworks. Using the built-in session handler they provide will probably more secure (and easier) than basic implementations of native PHP sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will have to create a session to remember them between clicks, otherwise you will have to tack on some sort of id in the GET parameters.

Take a look at `session_start()` and the examples they give you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Small warning, native PHP sessions have a vulnerability to session fixation, which could easily to session hijacking (they would need the session id, but after that, they could fix a session). It is always better to create a wrapper and do your best to ensure the user is who they say they are (via the session id) by comparing IPs and User Agents from previous clicks, stored in `$_SESSION`, to the current IP and User Agent they are presenting.

I personally recommend setting `session.use_only_cookies` to 1 to prevent information leaking via the session ID being passed in GET.

Comment: As far as i recall, session fixation is relatively easily prevented by clearing the session before initiating a new one. It should not deter you from using sessions.

Comment: Thanks for your advice samT . But I did not get your points on security issues . Can you explain a bit or any references will be helpful to me .Thanks

Comment: @Suraj Hazarika: This one does a decent job at explaining it: http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/4.html

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is indeed to use a session and the link SamT gave should suffice. But no need to store it to the database (yet).